# python ArgumentParser required optional arguments after parse_known_args not working properly

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using python `ArgumentParser` to handle a CLI program's user input. Which is a handy script named `smtp_mailer.py` for sending emails through SMTP protocol. I wish to use the CLI tool in two ways:

1. `./smtp_mailer.py <JSON representation of the mail>`;
2. `./smtp_mailer.py -u <user> -p <pass> -f <from> -t <to> ...`

So, I first use a parser to parse a `json` positional argument. If it were not provided, I continue parsing for `<user>/<port>/...` optional arguments:

```
def parse_args():
    # the positional argument `json`
    parser = ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('json', nargs='?', help='json representation of the SMTP mail')
    args, remaining_argv = parser.parse_known_args()

    if args.json:
        return args

    # the optional arguments
    parent = parser
    parser = ArgumentParser(parents=[parent], description='Send plain text mail through SMTP protocol.')
    parser.add_argument('-H', '--host', type=str, help='SMTP host')
    parser.add_argument('-P', '--port', type=int, help='SMTP port')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--user', type=str, required=True, help='SMTP username')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--pass', type=str, required=True, help='SMTP password')

    parser.add_argument('-f', '--from', type=str, required=True, help='mail FROM')
    parser.add_argument('-t', '--to', type=str, required=True, help='mail TO')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--cc', type=str, help='mail CC')
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--subject', type=str, required=True, help='mail SUBJECT')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--body', type=str, required=True, help='mail BODY')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--attachments', type=str, help='mail ATTACHMENTS')
    return parser.parse_args(remaining_argv)

def main():
    print parse_pargs()
```

But the parser seems not working properly as I expected if I didn't provide the `json` argument.

```
./smtp_mailer.py -u "Ggicci"
# output:
Namespace(json='Ggicci')
```

However, I expect to see:

```
usage: smtp_mailer.py [-h] [-H HOST] [-P PORT] -u USER -p PASS -f FROM -t TO
                      [-c CC] -s SUBJECT -b BODY [-a ATTACHMENTS]
smtp_mailer.py: error: argument -p/--pass is required
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parse_known_args` puts `'-u'` in `remaining_argv` and `'Ggicci'` in `args`.

Since `json` is a '?' positional, any non-flag string counts as a value, and if there are none, 'nothing' matches as well.  Your test would be more reliable if you defined a `--json` argument.